# spliting the string

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I have an string like this

```
string strdate =@"5/2/2006";
```

Which is in a  form  of  `month/day/year`.

I need  to  display it in a  form of like this `02-05-2006`.

**How  do i format the data like this?**

If the value is like this: `12/28/2005`, it should be displayed like this: `28-12-2010`.

I know  we should be splitting the data based on that we should do it.

I am not getting the syntax how to do it .

Any help  would be great.

Answer (score 10):

Parse the string into a `DateTime` and then use `ToString` with the right format to output it.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(@"5/2/2006", 
                                  "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string output = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

I suggest reading up on [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) date and time format strings.

Answer (score 1):

Read about how to parse `DateTime` string here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Then you read about how to print it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin

```
var datearray = strdate.split('/');

string date = datearray[0] + "-" + datearray[1] + "-" datearray[2]
```

**Issue 1**

This wont work from days from 10th to 31st... It will add leading zero to each day.
12-**0**5-2010 is good, but for ex. 12-**0**21-2010 is not good.

**Issue 2**
Wrong order of MM-dd

Answer (score -2):

You can use string.replace as such:

```
string newString = oldString.Replace('/', '-');
```

This will replace each '/' with '-' and create a new string, it will not replace it within the old string as strings are immutable.

Comment: You don't work with dates by splitting a string. Use the framework at hand!

Comment: Aah okay.  I read it as though he simply wanted to alter a number of characters within a string.